# doubt in file name

Tags: java, file

what is the difference b/w abstract pathname and pathname string. I came across these two when i was reading about string separator

Comment: So, please let us read that too, at least that particular instance, in order to help you.

Comment: aren't you speaking about relative vs absolute path ?

Comment: I think he read this http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @zengr: And I think the poster is "she". Yeah it happens sometimes with me too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that on *nix back slash (\) is valid character in a file name but not on windows.

Run this on windows and *nix and compare printouts:

```
File f1 = new File("c:\\somepath\\somefile.txt");
System.out.println(f1.getName()); 
File f2 = new File("c:/somepath/somefile.txt");
System.out.println(f2.getName());
```

On windows both variants prints `somefile.txt` but on *nix the first variant prints

```
c:\somepath\somefile.txt
```

second variant prints `somefile.txt`

So using / is "safer" to use. (Found this when uploading a file from a windows client to a Solaris server and trying to extract just the file name.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the system into which you ran your JVM.
For instance, Windows and Linux need different slash separator (forward/backward).
It's the separatorChar Value in File Class.
The Abstract PathName is independant from the system. This pathname is used internaly by The File Class. @see [File constructor doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the difference b/w abstract pathname and pathname string?**

An abstract pathname is basically a regular path name represented in a OS-independent way, while a pathname string is simply a (possibly system-dependent) string representing a path name.

The [documentation for File](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) elaborates a bit on this:

> *An abstract pathname has two components:*
>
> 1. *An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and*
> 2. *A sequence of zero or more string names.*

For example, the abstract version of the pathname string

```
"/home/aioobe/tmp/test.txt"
```

consists of these two parts:

1. A prefix: `"/"`
2. A list of string names

   1. `"home"`,
   2. `"aioobe"`,
   3. `"tmp"`,
   4. `"test.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

Pathname strings are used to name files and directories in various operating systems. They vary from OS to OS. For example, in Linux it is: `/home/user/a.java` and in Windows it: `c:\dev\a.java`

So, when it's said that a pathname string is converted to abstract pathname, that means that the pathname string is now independent of the OS.

For example:

```
File path = File("/home/user/a.java")
```

Converts the linux dependent file path to a **JVM understandable file path** (`path` object in above example), which is called Abstract path name.

I guess you have been reading [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html), but the best way to understand this is to implement a simple 5line java code and see what options with you get with the File class.

Answer (score 1):

**An abstract pathname has two components:**

1. An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and
2. A sequence of zero or more string names.

This is how Java internally represents a path to a resources in a OS independent manner.

A path name is the readable representation of that abstraction and is also what you could type into your OS terminal to reach that file, ie.

c:\blah\blah.txt